# How do you append a div to a container once a second?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find a good way to append a div to a container one at a time. I don't want to append all the divs and have them fade in one at a time. The code below is not working. Without the for loop it appends one at a time. I tried the for loop to limit the amount of times div gets appended sequentially but it output 4 divs every second. I want it to output one div once a second, four times.

```
for(var i = 0;i < 4; i++){
        setInterval(function(){
            $(".output").append("<div class='odiv'>TEST</div>")
        },1000)
 }
```

css:

```
.odiv{
        display: inline-block;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use timeout instead of interval with time as function of current iteration index `1000 * i`:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".output").append("<div class='odiv'>TEST</div>")
    }, 1000 * i);
}
```

```css
.odiv {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a counter in order to clear the interval:

```
var i = 0;
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (i === 4) return clearInterval(myInterval);
    $(".output").append("<div class='odiv'>TEST</div>");
    i++;
},1000);
```

Answer (score -3):

Your current code is running `$('.output').append()` four times each second. Here's a breakdown of what your current code is doing:

```
- Start a loop for 0,1,2,3
--- Loop 0
    Append a div to `.output` every 1000 milliseconds.
--- Loop 1
    Append a div to `.output` every 1000 milliseconds.
--- Loop 2
    Append a div to `.output` every 1000 milliseconds.
--- Loop 3
    Append a div to `.output` every 1000 milliseconds.
```

The result is 4 intervals appending the `.odiv` element every 1000 milliseconds.

You want to append a single `.odiv` element every 1000 milliseconds, for 4 seconds. To do this, create a function that appends a div each 1000 milliseconds and stop it after the 4th iteration.

```
var i = 0;
var appendDiv = setInterval(function() {
  if (i === 4) {
    // Stop the setInterval function from running
    clearInterval(appendDiv);
  } else (
    $(".output").append("<div class='odiv'>TEST</div>")
  )

  // Increase the counter
  i++
}, 1000)
```

Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/zqxhwLra/).

Comment: You're missing the timeout argument to `setInterval`

Comment: Please elaborate your anwer.